# Query regarding MVC: SubClass for DB activity

Tags: php, model-view-controller, oop

I just recently dove into OOP & now MVC and am using this template engine : http://www.milesj.me/resources/script/template-engine

I am curious about one question on where to put my DB calls (I'm using a basic database wrapper class).

I've seen two ways done.

class Cart

```
public static function count() {
    require_once(DATABASE .'cartext.php');
    $info = User::getInfo();
    $count = CartExt::inCart($info['0']['userid']);
    return $count;
}
```

Then in class CartExt

```
public static function inCart($shopperID) {
    $db = Database::getInstance();
    $query = $db->execute("SELECT * FROM Listing WHERE shopperid = '$shopperID'");
    $count = 0;
    while ($row = $db->fetchAll($query)) {
        $count++;
    }
    return $count;
}
```

With large functions I can see the advantage of separating the two, but a lot of the time it's as mundane as the example above, or worse: the base class just calls upon the Ext and returns its value! Also, I am doing a require_once from within the function to lower http requests if anyone is asking.

Anyway, I just want some thoughts on this.

Also, am I correct in that I should handle `$_POST['data']` in the controller and pass it as an param to my functions there, opposed to handling it within the class? (I'm not using a form object/class yet if it matters).

Looking forward to hearing your thoughts on this.

Comment: Now you made me ask: "doing a require_once to lower http requests"... What does that mean? :)

Comment: To only load that file when that function is being called.

Comment: Has nothing to do with HTTP requests though. Disk access, yes. :)

Answer (score 1):

Database calls should be executed from the **Model**.
If this goes via:

- mysql_query()
- a database wrapper
- an [ORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108699/good-php-orm-library) like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/)

doesn't matter as far as MVC is concerned. Although I can recommend the latter.

**Reasoning**
When you are storing data in a database that data usually represents model data: a User, an Order, etc.

**Exceptions**
If your storing sessions in the database or use the database for caching. These belong more to the Controller than the Model classes.